# fill data to collapse with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have a button .I want to When I click on this button fill the data add this collapse with javascript, but it does not.

Collapse works when I click the button, no problem here but data is not uploaded to collapse with javascript

My Button:

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_CommentPopup" data-note-id="@say_note.ID" class="btn btn-sm">Comments</button>
```

My Collapse:

```
@BootstrapLinkOrButton.collapsePopUp(id: "collapse_CommentPopup", title: "Yorumlar")  @*data-target,Herhangi bir title*@

@helper collapsePopUp(string id = "collapse_CommentPopup", string title = "Modal Title", bool showCloseButton = true)
{
    <div class="collapse fade" id="@id" name="@id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="@(id+"_labelPopup")">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body modalWrap" id="@(id+"_bodyPopup")">
                    "Default value"
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript :

```
    $("#collapse_CommentPopup").on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {

        var btn = $(e.relatedTarget);
        noteId = btn.data("note-id"); 

        $("#collapse_CommentPopup_bodyPopup").load("/Comment/ShowNoteComments/" + noteId); 
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you show the html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to get `note-id` from `e.relatedTarget` and it is not defined, you can get button data like this:

```js
$("#collapse_CommentPopup").on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  var btn = $('button[data-target="#' + e.target.id + '"]');
  noteId = btn.data("note-id");
  alert(noteId)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_CommentPopup" data-note-id="1" class="btn btn-sm">Comments</button>

<div class="collapse fade" id="collapse_CommentPopup" name="collapse_CommentPopup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="@(id+" _labelPopup ")">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body modalWrap" id="@(id+" _bodyPopup ")">
        "Default value"
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** If you want to get `note-id` just through `collapse` you can try this using `e.delegateTarget`:

```js
$("#collapse_CommentPopup").on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {

  alert(e.delegateTarget.previousElementSibling.dataset.noteId);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_CommentPopup" data-note-id="1" class="btn btn-sm">Comments</button>

<div class="collapse fade" id="collapse_CommentPopup" name="collapse_CommentPopup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="@(id+" _labelPopup ")">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body modalWrap" id="@(id+" _bodyPopup ")">
        "Default value"
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also find **value** of **data-note-id** attribute like this.

```js
$(document).on("show.bs.collapse", "#collapse_CommentPopup", function(e) {
  var noteId = $('[data-target="#'+e.currentTarget.id+'"]').data("note-id");
  console.log(noteId);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_CommentPopup" data-note-id="1" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">Comments</button>

<div class="collapse fade" id="collapse_CommentPopup" name="collapse_CommentPopup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="@(id+" _labelPopup ")">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body modalWrap" id="@(id+" _bodyPopup ")">
        "Default value"
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```